# How to handle quotes in passwords. PowerShell foreach loops

Tags: variables, powershell-3.0

I have searched high and low to no avail. The issue is when creating multiple service accounts in AD and assigning a randomly generated password from a csv list. If a password contains a single or double quote, the variable fails because it changes the terminating end quote. It can work if a variable is enclosed with single quotes and as long as there is an even number of quotes inside, but the moment there is an odd number of quotes, it always fails. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `.CSV` file. A properly formatted `.CSV` file will have the quote characters escaped.

e.g. Sample `.CSV` file:

```
UserName,Password
JSmith,"double""quote"
ASmith,single'quote
BSmith,"a space"
```

If the `.CSV` file is not formatted correctly, there is nothing PowerShell can do. e.g. I always use Excel for generating and saving `.CSV` files because it will automatically escape the quote characters for me.

Otherwise, you will have to treat your file as a list of text, and you will have to manually parse it yourself.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.